# How can I find the region given an EC2 instance ID (from outside the instance)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, region, aws-cli

I have the instance ID of an EC2 server. I need to find out the region it is located into in order to make `awscli` requests.

Is there a way to find the region of an instance given only its ID (`i-...`)? The only think I have in mind is to search each region on by one until I find it.

PS: I have to find this NOT from the instance itself.

Answer (score 2):

There is a discussion here about the Uniqueness of an EC2 Instance ID across Region.

[Are Amazon EC2 IDs globally unique across regions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/199630/are-amazon-ec2-ids-globally-unique-across-regions)

Based on this, I'm not sure if it's a bulletproof solution to query all the Regions. However, the chances that your account gets the same instance id in two different Region quiet low.

Other ideas depending on your scenarios. You may have Cloudtrail turned on and you can query the logs for the Instance ID.

Other option is to track your instances at startup/shutdown, you can even use the new Lambda service.... but it's a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server you can query all sorts of [instance metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) using the url http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ :

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone/
eu-west-1a
```

So the instance I just ran that command on is located in the eu-west-1 region in availability zone A.

Comment: I have to find that out from outside the instance, not from it.

Comment: Why the downvote?  You initially didn't mention that you had to do this from outside the instance, and this does work exactly as I documented.  It would have been a perfectly acceptable answer before you added the PS to your question.